# DVD or CD Player?

Tags: c++, hardware, detection, wmi-query, optical-drive

I want to know if my player is a DVD or CD Player, etc ...

I tried :

```
SELECT Drive, MediaType, Caption FROM Win32_CDROMDrive
```

`MediaType` doesn't work on XP, and not very well on Seven.

I tried on a computer (with Windows 7) with 1 player (Cd Writer/DVD-ROM) in MediaType I found `Cd Writer`.

Second solution :

I search in "Caption" if I find "DVD"

I tried a software, ([SIW - System Information for Windows](http://gtopala.com/)) and in my Player properties :

> Capabilities :
>
> CD Reader :    CD ROM, CD R, CD RW
>
> CD Writer :    CD R, CD RW
>
> DVD Reader :   DVD ROM, DVD R, DVD RW, DVD RAM
>
> DVD Writer :   No
>
> SMART Support : No

So, I want to know : with a WMI query (or other solution, I use C++), can I have the same informations or not?

It would be awesome if I could! If I can't, I just keep my "String parsing".

Comment: According to the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394587%28VS.85%29.aspx) you must check for the acronym `DVD` in the Name or DeviceID property of the Win32_CDROMDrive WMI class.

Comment: Yes, that's I say in my question (     `Caption` and      `Name` have the same values on my 3 computer) I can use `Name` / `DeviceID` instead of `Caption`

Comment: Are you tried the DeviceID property?

Comment: Yes, I do the same thing for `Caption` :  I search if "DVD" is in the result. I want to know if other solutions exist, and if I can find more information (If writer, etc...)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

to determine if a drive is DVD or CDROM , you can use the the [DeviceIoControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363216.aspx) function with the [IOCTL_STORAGE_GET_MEDIA_TYPES_EX](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363413.aspx) control code and then check the value of the DeviceType field of the [GET_MEDIA_TYPES](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363264.aspx) structure.

Try this sample

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include <winioctl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#define wszDrive L"\\\\.\\D:"
int wmain(int argc, wchar_t *argv[])
{
  BOOL bResult;     
  HANDLE hDevice = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;  // handle to the drive to be examined 
  hDevice = CreateFileW(wszDrive,          // drive to open
                        GENERIC_READ,             
                        FILE_SHARE_READ | // share mode
                        FILE_SHARE_WRITE, 
                        NULL,             // default security attributes
                        OPEN_EXISTING,    // disposition
                        0,                // file attributes
                        NULL);            // do not copy file attributes

  if (hDevice == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)    // cannot open the drive
  {
    return (FALSE);
  }

  UCHAR lpOutBuffer[2048];
  DWORD nOutBufferSize = sizeof(lpOutBuffer);
  ULONG lpBytesReturned;

  bResult = DeviceIoControl(hDevice,                       // device to be queried
                            IOCTL_STORAGE_GET_MEDIA_TYPES_EX, // operation to perform
                            NULL, 0,                       // no input buffer
                            &lpOutBuffer, nOutBufferSize, &lpBytesReturned,
                            NULL);       

  CloseHandle(hDevice);  
  PGET_MEDIA_TYPES pMediaTypes = (PGET_MEDIA_TYPES) lpOutBuffer;
  if (bResult) 
  {
      if (pMediaTypes->DeviceType==FILE_DEVICE_DVD)       
      {
          wprintf(L"DVD\n");
      }
      else
      if (pMediaTypes->DeviceType==FILE_DEVICE_CD_ROM)    
      {
          wprintf(L"CDROM\n");
      }
  } 
  else 
  {
    wprintf (L"Failed. Error %ld.\n", GetLastError ());
  }
  cin.get();
  return ((int)bResult);
}
```

Comment: OK ... I tried on : Seven (DVD) / Seven (CD-Writer/DVD) / XP (CD) / XP(DVD).It works ! Thanks :)

Comment: Does it support blu-ray drives?